Problems with RealTek 8822CU Wifi device on Linux 6.2
We have an embedded device that runs Linux 4.14.  It uses a USB Wifi adaptor that uses the RealTek 8822cu chipset.  Driver source code was provided by the vendor and compiled locally.  WiFi works well as both a station and access point.
We now have to update to Linux 6.2.  This version has native support for this chipset.  I have built the kernel and u-boot image based on Debian Bullseye for our device.  Everything works except for WiFi.  I am having two serious issues with it.  I am trying to connect to our device from a PC.  I have Wireshark running on the PC and tcpdump running on our device.

Tcpdump shows two identical packets being received for every packet sent from the PC.  When the PC broadcasts a DHCP request, our device responds with two identical DHCP ACKs.  The PC does not accept this and keeps sending DHCP requests.

When I enable WPA/WPA2 security on our device, DHCP broadcast messages are not passed to our device.  They do not show in the tcpdump trace and the PC will not be served an IP address.


This problem is not just with the PC.  We have a peripheral device that tries to connect via WiFi and it will not receive an IP address.
I've tried using newer versions of the driver, building from the Linux repository.  I also tried Linux kernel 6.1 (the earliest we can use) and backported the driver as outlined here: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88/.  We are bridging the WiFi interface with a wired ethernet interface.  We are also creating a second WiFi interface for our access point.  To simplify things I have disabled the bridge and run dhcpd and hostapd against the base wlan0 interface but still see the same problems.
If anyone has had similar problems or suggestions, I can provide more details on our environment.  I know enough about Linux to be dangerous but don't know what info to provide.
Update: I added loggong to hostapd and see the following messages repeated every second:
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc IEEE 802.11: authentication OK (open system)
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc MLME: MLME-AUTHENTICATE.indication(a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc, OPEN_SYSTEM)
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc MLME: MLME-DELETEKEYS.request(a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc)
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc IEEE 802.11: association OK (aid 1)
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc MLME: MLME-ASSOCIATE.indication(a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc)
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc MLME: MLME-DELETEKEYS.request(a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc)
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc IEEE 802.11: binding station to interface 'wlan1'
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc WPA: event 1 notification
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc WPA: start authentication
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc IEEE 802.1X: unauthorizing port
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc WPA: sending 1/4 msg of 4-Way Handshake
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc WPA: received EAPOL-Key frame (2/4 Pairwise)
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc WPA: sending 3/4 msg of 4-Way Handshake
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc WPA: received EAPOL-Key frame (4/4 Pairwise)
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc IEEE 802.1X: authorizing port
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc RADIUS: starting accounting session C0EA550B8953E71B
Jul 12 19:13:20 mspmbsat hostapd[295]: wlan1: STA a0:29:42:5c:b3:cc WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)

This is with WPA2 enabled.
